# Render Angular component via Wordpress REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angular, wordpress-rest-api, angular-pipe

I have an Angular 5 app that is using content from Wordpress via the REST API.

What I'd like to do is insert a component tag in the Wordpress content editor and then have it appear in the app.

For example, I created a simple component `<app-some-component></app-some-component>`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  template: `
  <h1>I am a component!</h1>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and added it directly to the host component template to test it, it works.

Now, this host component is also pulling content from Wordpress via the rest API. So I try adding `<app-some-component></app-some-component>` in the Wordpress content editor.

The tag "comes through" to the Angular app and I see the tag in the HTML when inspecting the page.  But the content of the component does not render, so I guess it is not being processed by Angular.

I am using a Safe Pipe to allow HTML in the component, as in

```
        <div class="card"
           *ngFor="let vid of videolist">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid"
             [src]="vid.better_featured_image.source_url"
             alt="Video Thumbnail">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"
              [innerHTML]="vid.title.rendered"></h4>
          <p class="card-text"
             [innerHTML]="vid.content.rendered | safe: 'html'"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <a routerLink="/videos/{{vid.id}}">View Video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The pipe's code is

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })

// see https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b
// usage: <div [innerHtml]="htmlSnippet | safe: 'html'"></div>
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);

      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get the component to render?

Answer (score 0):

This is just writing plain html to the dom, youu need Angular to actually render that as components. For that you have some alternatives:

### You can write a component with a lot of `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` directives:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post',
  template: `
    <article>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of datas">
        <app-component-1 [data]="data" *ngIf="data.type === '1'"></app-component-1>
        <app-component-2 [data]="data" *ngIf="data.type === '2'"></app-component-2>
        <app-component-3 [data]="data" *ngIf="data.type === '3'"></app-component-3>
      </ng-container>
    </article>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./blog-post.component.scss'],
})
export class BlogPostComponent {
  @Input() datas: any[]
}
```

### You can use the [Angular Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) to render the components programmatically:

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core'
import { Component1 } from '../component-1/component-1.component'
import { Component2 } from '../component-2/component-2.component'
import { Component3 } from '../component-3/component-3.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post',
  template: `
    <article>
      <app-blog-post-micro-component *ngFor="let data of datas" [data]="data"></app-blog-post-micro-component>
    </article>
  `,
})
export class BlogPostComponent {
  @Input() datas: any[]
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post-micro-component',
  template: '<ng-container #container></ng-container>',
})
export class BlogPostMicroComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any[]
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) private container: ViewContainerRef

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Prepare to render the right component
    const component = this.getComponentByType(this.data.type)
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component)

    // Clear the view before rendering the component
    const viewContainerRef = this.container
    viewContainerRef.clear()

    // Create component
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory)
    componentRef.instance.data = this.data
  }

  private getComponentByType(type: string) {
    const componentMapByType = { '1': Component1, '2': Component2, '3': Component3 }
    return componentMapByType[type]
  }
}
```

You should read this article to learn more: [Angular Dynamic Components](https://medium.com/calyx/angular-dynamic-components-ffd16947fbef)

Comment: I'm not sure how this would get the component specified in the HTML in wordpress to render in my app.  We have several components used in the Angular app.  I'm trying to find a way that my content people in wordpress can drop a component tag the same way I would in the actual app's code.

Comment: I get it but I don't think you can do it your way as of now. I tried to do it this way too but failed to find any documentation regarding how to do it.

Comment: I've used those elsewhere, but I don't understand how that would make angular recognize and render the component HTML being sent in an `innerHTML` binding from Wordpress.